# How to tell if LLVM Instruction has a Left-Hand Side

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Is there a way to tell if an LLVM `Instruction` has a left-hand side?  That is, whether it produces a value?

For example, an `add` instruction would have a left-hand side; however, a `store` or `br` instruction would not.

Comment: Do you need to perform such a check in your code or do you just want to know which instruction might or might not have a result assignment?

Comment: If there are not uses or user for the Value of the instruction then that instruction doesn't has left-hand side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general you can identify those instructions which *cannot* have a result assignment, but you cannot say if an instruction will result in an assignment, only that it *might*.

This is because you don't *have* to assign the result of an operation. For instance, the following line of code is valid in LLVM IR:

```
add nsw i32 %a, %b
```

but it's pointless because it has no effect whatsoever. No sane tool would emit that line, and even if emitted, it would be wiped away by the optimizer during dead code elimination. The only instruction for which ignoring the return value actually makes sense is `call`. In fact, you might want to call a function only for side-effects, even when it's not declared `void`. Think about `printf` in C, whose return value is almost invariably ignored.

Because of this last consideration, you can assume that in practice all the instructions that can have a result assignment will have one, with the only exception of `call`. `invoke` is very similar to `call`, so the same considerations made for the former apply.

As you might have noticed, whether an instruction results in an assignment  depends on its class. With the help of [`llvm/IR/Instruction.def`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def), which contains the definition of all opcodes and classes, and [the IR language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html), we can come up with the following subdivision:

### Instruction classes that cannot have a result assignment:

- `ReturnInst`, `BranchInst`, `SwitchInst`, `IndirectBrInst`, `ResumeInst`, `UnreachableInst`, `CleanupReturnInst`, `CatchReturnInst`
- `StoreInst`, `FenceInst`, `AtomicRMWInst`, `AtomicCmpXchgInst`

### Instruction classes that (might) have a result assignment:

- `CatchSwitchInst`
- `BinaryOperator`
- `AllocaInst`, `LoadInst`, `GetElementPtrInst`
- `InvokeInst`, `CatchSwitchInst`
- `TruncInst`, `ZExtInst`, `SExtInst`, `FPToUIInst`, `FPToSIInst`, `UIToFPInst`, `SIToFPInst`, `FPTruncInst`, `FPExtInst`, `PtrToIntInst`, `IntToPtrInst`, `BitCastInst`
- `VAArgInst`
- `CleanupPad`, `CatchPad`
- `ICmpInst`, `FCmpInst`, `PHINode`, `SelectInst`
- `ExtractElementInst`, `ShuffleVectorInst`, `ExtractValueInst`, `InsertElementInst`, `InsertValueInst`

### Instruction classes that might or might not have a result assignment:

- `CallInst`, `InvokeInst`

You can now build a `switch` on the result of `Instruction::getOpcode()` or, better, an [`InstVisitor`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1InstVisitor.html#details) to classify instructions:

```
#include <llvm/IR/InstVisitor.h>

enum HaveRetVal { DEFINITELY_NOT, MAYBE, PROBABLY_YES };

class HaveRetAssignment : public InstVisitor<HaveRetAssignment, HaveRetVal> {
public:
  HaveRetVal visitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator &) { return PROBABLY_YES; }

  // ...

  HaveRetVal visitCallInst(CallInst&) { return MAYBE; }

  // ...

  HaveRetVal visitBranchInst(BranchInst&) { return DEFINITELY_NOT; }

  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check whether the return type of the instruction is `void`:

```
getType()->isVoidTy()
```