# LLVM: difference between "uses" and "user" in Instruction or Value classes

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am new in LLVM and have checked `Value` and `Instruction` classes. I see that both of these classes have the methods `uses` and `user`. What are the differences between them? Also, regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865535/how-to-tell-if-llvm-instruction-as-a-left-hand-side), can I use these methods to determine if an instruction produces a value?

tnx.

Comment: Note that, not every user is an instruction, i.e., A user may be an expression as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found this answer in "Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries" book.

We have still not presented the most powerful aspect of the LLVM IR (enabled by
the SSA form): the Value and User interfaces; these allow you to easily navigate the
use-def and def-use chains. In the LLVM in-memory IR, a class that inherits from
Value means that it defines a result that can be used by others, whereas a subclass
of User means that this entity uses one or more Value interfaces. Function and
Instruction are subclasses of both Value and User, while BasicBlock is a subclass
of just Value. To understand this, let's analyze these two classes in depth:

• The Value class defines the `use_begin()` and `use_end()` methods to allow
you to iterate through Users, offering an easy way to access its def-use chain.
For every Value class, you can also access its name through the `getName()`
method. This models the fact that any LLVM value can have a distinct identifier
associated with it. For example, `%add1` can identify the result of an add
instruction, BB1 can identify a basic block, and myfunc can identify a function.
Value also has a powerful method called `replaceAllUsesWith(Value *)`,
which navigates through all of the users of this value and replaces it with
some other value. This is a good example of how the SSA form allows you to
easily substitute instructions and write fast optimizations. You can view the
full interface at [LLVM Value Class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html).

• The User class has the `op_begin()` and `op_end()` methods that allows
you to quickly access all of the Value interfaces that it uses. Note that this
represents the use-def chain. You can also use a helper method called
`replaceUsesOfWith(Value *From, Value *To)` to replace any of its used
values. You can view the full interface at [LLVM User Class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1User.html).

Comment: "Note that this represents the use-def chain" - I may be missing something but it seems that `op_begin`/`op_end` simply provide access to `User`'s operands whereas use-def chains [map use of variable to its definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-define_chain).

Answer (score 21):

Since `Instruction` is derived from `Value` it inherits both functions `users` and `uses`. The difference is that a user of `Value` has the `Value` as one of its operands.

When you are calling `uses` you get a list of all `Use` instances holding a reference from the `Value` to each of the users of the particular `Value`. Calling `users` gives you a list of  `User` directly. The following code shows how to use `users` and `uses`.

```
for(auto U : V->users()){  // U is of type User*
     if (auto I = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U)){
        // an instruction uses V
     }
}
```

You can see `users` as a shortcut because you can do the same with uses:

```
for(auto U : V->uses()){  // U is of type Use*
     if (auto I = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U.getUser())){
        // an instruction uses V
     }
}
```

Commonly it is enough to use `users` to get all dependencies of a `Value`.

All Values used by a `Value` are the operands. This direction of dependency is not part of a `Value`'s use list.

To the second question regarding instructions producing a value: there is no guarantee that the absence of uses results from not producing a value. A dead instruction can produce a value and has no users. Additionally, an instruction not producing a value can be used by metadata .

Comment: So, Uses gives all the instructions/values that the particular Value depends on and Users give all the instructions/values that depend on that particular value, right?

Comment: user get the instructions, and uses get the particular values. When you wanna replace a 'variable '(value) with another, you must replace every use.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that number of `users()` always equals to the number of `uses()`.

Comment: @Carlos No, both Uses and Users get the Values that depend on the target value. Suppose you have a Value `a`. `a.users()` gives you the list of Values that use `a`. `a.uses()` returns the Use objects, on which you can call `getUser()` to get the value that uses `a`, or `get()` to get `a` itself. To get the list of Values that `a` uses, call `a.operands()`.